# Django Admin Site -- view path "admin/" at "/"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I'm developing a Django (3.1) app that **only** uses the [Admin Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/).

The default behavior is then to serve the Admin Site with the path:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/
```

Which assumes that you have other sites at `http://localhost:8080/other_site`

Because my only site is the Admin Site, I'd like to serve the admin site at:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

without the `admin/`.

Here is the file `website/urls.py` (website folder has all the settings/config)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('management/', include('management.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And here is the file `management/urls.py` (management is the app with all the models)

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**How can I do this?**

---

I've tried updating `website/urls.py` to include this

```
#path('management/', include('management.urls')),
path('/', admin.site.urls),
```

which I thought would disable the `management` endpoint (it does) but it does not point the home path to the Admin Site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the url, just delete the `admin/`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('management/', include('management.urls')),
    path('', admin.site.urls), # here is a change
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: ah, very nice, thanks. I had tried it with "/" but that didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, django is very punctual about this, but when you look even inside your ```management/urls.py``` you can see, that you also use the ```path('', views.index)``` instead of putting the ```/``` inside of the quotes